# Combinations of string algorithm C#

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, substring

So i recently had an interview where one the question was as below. I have been thinking for a while as to how to solve this. Does anyone know? I have found out that is to do with the combination of strings algorithm.

A `string` consisting of `'x'` and `'y'` is given. The task is to split it into `3` seperate parts so that each part contains the *same number* of letters of `'y'`. In how many ways can the string be split.

For example:

Input: `"xyxyy"`

Output: `"xy | xy | y", "xyx | y | y"`

If anyone can give me some sort of clue on what I need to know to figure this out or, even better, if you show a code explaining how this could be done that will be great!

Thanks

Comment: First possibility: next segment right after every y; last possibility: next segment right before every y. Then go through everything in between with all combinations.

Comment: Well, it depends on the number of xs between the ys. It doesn't seem like a programming question per se though. It might be a better fit for [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple math will do. So you have a string with `3n` `'y'` (otherwise you can't split the string at all).
The string is something like this:

```
 aybcdy ... eypq...raybcdy ...  eyvw..zybcdy ...  ey
 <--- n 'y'-->       <--- n 'y'-->     <--- n 'y'-->
```

Note that chunks with `y` a fixed but characters between these parts can be added either to one part or to another:

```
aybcdy ... ey | pq...raybcdy ...  ey # 1st possibility
<--- n 'y'-->          <--- n 'y'-->

aybcdy ... eyp | q...raybcdy ...  ey # 2nd possibility
<--- n 'y'-->          <--- n 'y'-->

aybcdy ... eypq | ...raybcdy ...  ey # 3d possibility
<--- n 'y'-->          <--- n 'y'-->

...

aybcdy ... eypq...ra | ybcdy ...  ey # the last possibility
<--- n 'y'-->          <--- n 'y'-->
```

So far we have `(P + 1) * (Q + 1)` possibilities to split the string into 3 chunks where

- `P` - characters between `N`-th and `N+1`-st `'y'`
- `Q` - characters between `2N`-th and `2N+1`-st `'y'`

**Code:**

```
private static int Solution(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    return 0;

  int N = value.Count(c => c =='y');

  if (N % 3 != 0 || N == 0) // let's return 0 if we don' have 'y's
    return 0;

  N = N / 3;

  int P = 0;
  int Q = 0;   
  int y = 0;

  foreach (char c in value) {
    if (c == 'y')
      y += 1;
    else if (y == N)
      ++P;
    else if (y == 2 * N) 
      ++Q;
  }

  return (P + 1) * (Q + 1);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(Solution("xyxyy"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
2
```

If you want to obtain splits:

```
private static IEnumerable<string[]> SolutionSplits(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    yield break;

  int N = value.Count(c => c == 'y');

  if (N % 3 != 0 || N == 0) // let's return empty if we don' have 'y's
    yield break;

  N = N / 3;

  List<int> P = new List<int>();
  List<int> Q = new List<int>();
  int y = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char c = value[i];

    if (c == 'y')
      y += 1;

    if (y == N)
      P.Add(i);
    else if (y == 2 * N)
      Q.Add(i);
  }

  foreach (int p in P)
    foreach (int q in Q)
      yield return new string[] {
        value.Substring(0, p + 1),
        value.Substring(p + 1, q - p),
        value.Substring(q + 1)}; 
}
```

**Demo:**

```
 string source = "xyxyy";
 
 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, SolutionSplits(source)
   .Select(items => string.Join(" | ", items)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 xy | xy | y
 xyx | y | y
```

Comment: Actually if the letter doesn't exist in the string then the answer would be the number of ways you can split the string into 3 parts since each part would have 0 instances of the letter.  Presumably you wouldn't include empty strings in that calculation though.